# Values are getting overridding wile saving data into localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I just stared building a to do list. My approch is to save the data in first tab and show it on second tab. I am able to save the data in to local storage. But data is getting overridding for me. Any idea where I am doing mistake.

Here is my jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/saorabh/RmCA7/

Used HTML is

```
<form id="todo-form">
                <input type="text" name="t_title" id="t_title" placeholder="Title" />
                <textarea placeholder="Description" name="t_description" id="t_description"></textarea>
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Task"/>
              </form>
```

To save data my Javascript is

```
$(".btn-primary").click(function(){
    var formId = ("todo-form");
var inputs = $("#" + formId + " :input"),
            id, title, description, tempData,
            data = {} ;

        title = inputs[0].value;
        description = inputs[1].value;

        id = new Date().getTime();

        tempData = {
            id : id,
            title: title,
            description: description
        };

        // Saving element in local storage
        data[id] = tempData;
        localStorage.setItem("todoData", JSON.stringify(tempData));

});
```

Comment: `localStorage.setItem("todoData", JSON.stringify(tempData));` - as I remember, localStorage works like hashtable. So every time you rewrite value for the same key. So you always have only one pair (key - value) in localStorage. You should use different keys or making value as array, adding new data to the end of this array

Comment: You are saving data for same key = todoData, so every time you click button it will override. Use different key for different click.

Comment: Yes correct, thats why I am generating id = new Date().getTime(). To make every entry unique.

Answer (score 1):

The LocalStorage is a key/value pair storage, so for each key you can only have one value.

You is always setting the value to the key 'todoData', so you always replace the last value by the current one.

If you intend to only use one key for all the data you should parse your JSON from the LocalStore, append the second item and them store it again on LocalStorage. Or you can use multiple keys.

Besides that, there are two issues in you code:

- You are saving the wrong object, you should save `data` and not
  `tempData`
- You are not recreating the `data` object from the
  localStorage when the page is loaded

http://jsfiddle.net/RmCA7/4/

Comment: can u supply jsFiddle ?